# How to fill DataGridView from left to right, instead of top to bottom

Tags: c#, datagridview

How do I display a datasource in DataGridView from left to right in a row, instead of top to bottom in a column?

Thanks!

Comment: Change your datasource so that's how the data is arranged?

Comment: I have a list of a list of a class which contains dates and doubles, how would you change how its arranged to make it display left to right?

Comment: Smells of a double loop

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the list or the math; I don't know how to use DataGridView.

Comment: DataGrids tend to be pretty inflexible about the role of rows and columns. Are you really sure you need this? Because it's going to cost you.

Comment: Is there a better solution to show a spreadsheet style of data?

Comment: Your requirement sounds odd. Your last comment: _Is there a better solution to show a spreadsheet style of data?_ sounds odd because that is exactly what a `DataGridView` does. Like an Excel spreadsheet, the columns represent single entities/values and the rows represent a record or a class element where each column in the row represents and entity of that record or class. Flopping this would mean the each column represent a record and each row represents an entity. This may lead to the possibility of an unknown number of columns because each column is a record.

Comment: So you may have 5 rows of entities but a thousand columns of records. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to display the columns in a DataGridView horizontally, instead of vertically, the only option you have is to pivot (flip) the dataset and then bind it to the grid. You can use the following code:

```
public DataSet FlipDataSet(DataSet my_DataSet)
{
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

 foreach (DataTable dt in my_DataSet.Tables)
 {
   DataTable table = new DataTable();

   for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {   table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));  }

   DataRow r;
   for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
   { 
     r = table.NewRow();
     r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
     for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)
     {  r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k]; }
     table.Rows.Add(r);
   }
   ds.Tables.Add(table);
 }

 return ds;
}
```

The approach is well explained [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19313/displaying-vertical-rows-in-datagrid-view)